# What is the equivalent of Puppet's `unless` in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

**Background:** in Puppet it is possible to execute a command [unless](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-unless) it has already been executed:

> ```
> exec { '/bin/echo root >> /usr/lib/cron/cron.allow':
>   path   => '/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin',
>   unless => 'grep root /usr/lib/cron/cron.allow 2>/dev/null',
> }
> ```

**Aim:** to execute a command unless it has already been run in Ansible

**Methods**

*tasks/main.yml*

```
- name: add vhost sensu
  command: rabbitmqctl add_vhost /sensu
```

**Results**

```
TASK [ansible-rabbitmq : add vhost sensu] **************************************
fatal: [111.222.333.444]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["rabbitmqctl",
"add_vhost", "/sensu"], "delta": "0:00:00.210140", "end": 
"2016-07-29 12:55:19.384455", "failed": true, "rc": 2, "start":
"2016-07-29 12:55:19.174315", "stderr": "Error: vhost_already_exists: /sensu", 
"stdout": "Creating vhost \"/sensu\" ...", "stdout_lines": 
["Creating vhost \"/sensu\" ..."], "warnings": []}
```

**Discussion**

Googling `unless ansible` showed [this document about `when`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement). Based on that documentation, a `when` statement was added:

```
- name: add vhost sensu
  command: rabbitmqctl add_vhost /sensu
  when: rabbitmqctl list_vhosts | grep sensu
```

running the code resulted in:

```
fatal: [192.168.0.9]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional
 check 'rabbitmqctl list_vhosts | grep sensu' failed. The error was: template
 error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got
 'list_vhosts'. String: {% if rabbitmqctl list_vhosts | grep sensu %} True {%
 else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible
/roles/ansible-rabbitmq/tasks/main.yml': line 10, column 3, but may\nbe
 elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe
 offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: add vhost sensu\n  ^ here\n"}
```

1. First of all, imagine that `when` was successful then the command will not run and then it looks more like [`onlyif` in Puppet](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-onlyif).
2. Secondly, if the when would be successful should an escalation mark be used in order to simulate an unless?
3. [Use of `register`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19883879/2777965). What if that file is lost or the vhost has been removed by for example a human? Puppet's `unless` always executes the commands so that it is clear whether the command needs to be executed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you're looking do is this:

```
- name: get vhosts
  command: rabbitmqctl list_vhosts
  register: vhosts
  changed_when: false

- name: add vhost sensu
  command: rabbitmqctl add_vhost /sensu
  when: "'/sensu' not in vhosts.stdout"
```

Re: #3 `register` does not create a file. If you're capturing the output of `rabbitmqctl list_vhosts` via `register`, the contents will be as valid as the system's current state.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the line `when: rabbitmqctl list_vhosts | grep sensu`. It is not possible to use bash here.

You need to put the `rabbitmqctl list_vhosts | grep sensu` in a separate task and register the result to use it in the when clause. You can use `not` filter to get `unless` like behavior.

Something like this should work:

```
- name: Get rabbitmq vhosts.
  command: rabbitmqctl list_vhosts | grep sensu
  register: rabbitmq_vhosts

- name: add vhost sensu
  command: rabbitmqctl add_vhost /sensu
  when: not 'sensu' in rabbitmq_vhosts.stdout
```

The `Get rabbitmq vhosts.` in this example will always be executed. The `add vhost sensu` only if the string sensu is not in the registered `rabbitmq_vhosts`.

Consult the documentation on [conditionals](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html) and [jinja filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#filters-often-used-with-conditionals) for more information.

Comment: The issue persists: `fatal: [IP]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["rabbitmqctl", "add_vhost", "/sensu"], "delta": "0:00:00.198681", "end": "2016-07-29 13:43:00.870193", "failed": true, "rc": 2, "start": "2016-07-29 13:43:00.671512", "stderr": "Error: vhost_already_exists: /sensu", "stdout": "Creating vhost \"/sensu\" ...", "stdout_lines": ["Creating vhost \"/sensu\" ..."], "warnings": []}`

Comment: hm, probably my fault. I guess it was a missing `.stdout` edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The `when` option is the only thing Ansible has regarding conditions. But you can not directly define a command there. `when` expects a Jinja expression and furthermore is evaluated on the Ansible control host. So you first need to run a task to fetch the result and register it.

```
- shell: rabbitmqctl list_vhosts | grep sensu
  register: sensu_vhosts

- name: add vhost sensu
  command: rabbitmqctl add_vhost /sensu
  when: sensu_vhosts.stdout_lines < 1
```

`stdout_lines` is an array of all lines the shell task returned. So you can count the number of entries and only run your task when 0 items have been returned

Comment: if the /sensu vhost does not exist it results in: `fatal: [IP]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "rabbitmqctl list_vhosts | grep sensu", "delta": "0:00:00.198769", "end": "2016-07-29 13:45:59.069981", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2016-07-29 13:45:58.871212", "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}`